# Voto bloqueado en una respuesta, ¿si no se edita no se puede retirar el voto negativo?

Tags: discusión

Voté negativamente una respuesta porque no estaba de acuerdo con ella. Luego el autor de la misma en un comentario me aclaró un aspecto que me hizo decidir retirar el voto negativo e incluso votar a favor.

Sin embargo no fue posible, saliéndome este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- ¿La respuesta tiene que ser editada necesariamente para poder retirar mi voto en contra?
- ¿Si la pregunta no se edita esta situación permanece así de forma indefinida o es algo temporal (el mensaje no es claro en ese sentido, al hablar de *hace una hora* hace pensar que es un bloque temporal, pero tampoco lo dice claro) ?

Comment: Si pasan 5 minutos, ya no se puede rectificar el voto. El mismo limite que para editar un comentario. Si, ha de editarse la publicacion para poder cambiar el voto. Porque normalmente es tras una edición cuando la valoracion de la publicacion puede cambiar. Recuerda hacer una edición sustancial si quieres cambiar el voto. Un saludo

Comment: Sugiero usar tus poderes para editar la publicación si hay aspectos para mejorar, sin entrar en conflicto con la intención del autor. Los que consideres necesarios, de esta manera podrías revocar el voto negativo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿La respuesta tiene que ser editada necesariamente para poder retirar
>   mi voto en contra?

Modificar tu voto es posible si han transcurrido 5 minutos o más no se puede modificar el voto a menos que se realice una edición en la publicación, esto también se indica en el mensaje al usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Si la pregunta no se edita esta situación permanece así de forma
>   indefinida o es algo temporal (el mensaje no es claro en ese sentido,
>   al hablar de hace una hora hace pensar que es un bloque temporal, pero
>   tampoco lo dice claro) ?

Mientras la pregunta se edite después de tu haber votado, puedes volver a modificar la votación, después de esto, si transcurren 5 minutos ya no permitirá modificaciones en el voto.

**Podrías sugerirle al autor de la publicación que agregué la información que te llevo a decidir que la respuesta en realidad no era incorrecta, de esta forma podrías modificar el voto.**

---

Revisa de la publicación original de [@Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9):

[No se puede cambiar el voto aunque la publicación haya sido editada.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256606/cannot-change-vote-even-though-the-post-has-been-edited)(inglés)

> A partir de ahora, sería posible retractar / revertir una votación en
>   los casos en que la edición de la publicación ocurra después de que el
>   votante (o "alguien que no sea el editor" comentó), consulte
>   Restablecer el período de gracia de la pregunta una vez que se haya
>   publicado la respuesta:
>
> Las ediciones se incorporarán a la revisión anterior si la revisión
>   anterior fue creada por el mismo autor y no se cumple ninguna de las
>   siguientes condiciones:
>
> - La revisión anterior fue creada 5 minutos o más en el pasado.
> - Se ha agregado un comentario a la publicación desde la revisión anterior por cualquier persona que no sea el editor.
> - Se ha añadido una respuesta a la publicación desde la revisión anterior.
> - La revisión anterior fue una reversión
> - La nueva revisión es una reversión ...
>
> Vale la pena tener en cuenta que los votos emitidos sin comentarios se
>   atascarían si las ediciones posteriores se realizan dentro del período
>   de gracia.